# Change Caret Color in WinRT?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

So in WPF and Silverlight you could set the caret color for TextBox using TextBox.CaretBrush, but in WinRT it seems in all their wisdom they removed this property. So now if the TextBox is a dark color, since it defaults the caret color to black you can't see it, and if the background color of your TextBox is black the caret ceases to exist completely.  I find this completely illogical, there has got to be a way to change the caret color, either pragmatically or something?

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to edit the right properties in the control template. I believe for WinRT it's in like *generic.xaml but I'm not positive that's the correct resource dictionary, hence not put as an answer though I'm pretty sure that's all you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by overlaying a transparent canvas overtop of the TextBox, using SelectionStart and GetRectFromCharIndex to obtain coordinates, then on KeyDown, KeyUp, and MouseDown I set the coordinates of a Line and use a TranslateTransform to move it, works great and performance is fantastic!

Not sure why I didn't try this first, I've done Transforms in Silverlight and WPF many times prior. I guess the subtle differences in WinRt kind of threw me for a loop...

Comment: I want to add to this that for multi-line textbox this does not work because the GetRectFromCharIndex will not give you the correct Y coordinate with a new line and no text on it until text is added.  But it does work great for Single lines textboxes with a caveat.  You need to use Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyPressed for Left/Right/End/Home,etc. keys as KeyDown for TextBox does not fire for these keys (also odd behavior IMO).

Comment: I might try to do this in an HTML 5 version Metro app because I think it would be substantially easier to do since the WinRT version of XAML is total garbage...

Comment: Can you kindly share your solution please? I'm in need to do something similar and am curious as to how you did it.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. You [need to](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/26bc26d1-574d-48c1-9a00-5096c55cdbd3) switch your TextBox to light background when it has focus so the caret is visible.

Comment: This does not confine to the user experience I am looking to generate in my application and is not an acceptable answer. I found that answer before posting my question, trust me when I say Google does not have this answer...

Comment: Well, if Rob says you need to use a workaround - that basically means it is not possible to change it, so this is the only answer you will get. Unless there is some hack. The themeresources.xaml file you can find in "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\WinRT\Xaml\Design\themeresources.xaml" does not mention a caret, so Chris's comment is not a good answer here.

Comment: I am actually leaning towards figuring out the x, y position of the caret and showing my own custom drawable at those coordinates at this point.

Comment: Heck I don't even see a way to draw objects onto thing, I am starting to think WinRT is pretty awful here...

Comment: This looks promising, I'll try this and if it works I will post as my solution: https://github.com/christophwille/winrt-render-text-to-bitmap/blob/master/RenderTextToBitmap/RenderTextToBitmap/MainPage.xaml.cs (obiously he is using it draw text, I will use it to Draw my caret)

Comment: While the example you linked is very interesting - you don't really need DirectX to draw a caret. You can just use one or a couple of Line shape objects. Determining the caret position might be a little bit difficult though. Also you would need to remove the existing caret first unless you are planning on completely covering it with yours. Overall - anything you will do is an overkill and the workaround I mention is a better evil than what you are facing here, which is basically implementing your own TextBox control.

Comment: Hi Filip, what work around did you mention? I see you mention that its not possible and tell me its not mentioned in ThemeResources.xaml which I already knew.  But I don't see you offer me a work around, unless you are talking about changing it to a light background which simply won't work for my app.  Also you can't draw Lines without using DirectX unless you add it to the Visual Tree which would suck for perf, unless I am missing something.  If you can show me how to draw lines on a TextBox that would make my day...(Not using Inking API)

Comment: Why wouldn't the light background workaround work for your app? IE uses it with no issues. I don't think adding a line to the visual tree would affect your perf. You could even use RenderTranforms for positioning and reposition it from any thread. Loading DX components is much more complicated and might actually be slower since you would need to render another surface...

Comment: It won't work because the TextBox is the centerpiece of the entire application, the user has focus on it at all times...

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party on this question but I ran into the same issue and found an easy work-around.  On the Windows 8.1 RT preview I noticed that overriding the TextBoxForegroundThemeBrush changes the caret or cursor color for TextBox.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBoxForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
```

Typically the cursor is always black, even when you override the Style and ControlTemplate.  I happened to stumble on this by looking in the ThemeResources.xaml that Filip mentioned above.  I'm not sure if this applies to pre-8.1 xaml, Microsoft seems to have cleaned a lot up in new SDK.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. I'm using Windows 8.1 and set the TextBoxForegroundThemeBrush, but the caret is still black. I've tried to change it in the ThemeResources.xaml file or overriding it in my page's resources, but to no avail. Anything I'm missing? Did you get it to work in the final version of Windows 8.1?