# Substitute of CaretBrush in windows store application

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Can anyone tell that what is the substitute of [CaretBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretbrush%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property of textbox, which is available in WPF & Windows Phone in windows store application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18938876/1230188